# Can I install Samba while running on LiveUSB?

Tags: installation, samba, live-cd

I'm brand new to Ubuntu.  I loaded Ubuntu `12.04` on a `USB stick` so that I could use the terminal to fix a problem with my android phone.  When I try to install `Samba`, I get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2) but 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2) but 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
     Recommends: tdb-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is it because I'm trying to do this before installing Ubuntu, just running it from the USB? Or is there another problem that I'm missing?  Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you need to first run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install Samba.  That will take some space, but might not be too bad on 12.04.3
Possibly you could install an older version of Samba, but not sure how that would go, since I've never tried to "go back" for an install.